# Why is this mock value not returned in the code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mocking, moq

I have a .NET Core 6 function with the following code:

```
var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().ToList();
```

I setup mocking to mock certain objects in that function to get records using `Moq.Mock` as per the snippet below. There is other code too, but this is snipped down version.

```
var myList = new List<MyClass>();
var obj= new MyClass{ ID = "123", Name = "ABC" };
myList.Add(obj);

var csvReaderMock = new Mock<CsvReader>(It.IsAny<StreamReader>(), It.IsAny<CsvConfiguration>());
csvReaderMock.Setup(m => m.GetRecords<MyClass>()).Returns(myList);
```

As you can see I have setup the `csvReader` mock to return my predefined list using

```
csvReaderMock.Setup(m => m.GetRecords<MyClass>()).Returns(myList);
```

but it doesn't return the mocked values in the class.

Note: I can't change this line as of now `var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))` and need to find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see I have setup the csvReader mock to return my predefined list using csvReaderMock.Setup(m => m.GetRecords()).Returns(myList);, but it doesn't return the mocked value in the class.

Yes, you've set up the `csvReaderMock` object so that it has that particular behaviour specified in the `Setup` method.

This means that `csvReaderMock.Object` is a `CsvReader` object with that behaviour. That object is going to be the *only* object with that behaviour. Specifically, it doesn't change the behaviour of the `csv` object in your other code; that object is *another* object.

> Note: I can't change this line as of now var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config)) and need to find a workaround.

If you can't change that line, you can't modify the `csv` object's behaviour with Moq, nor with most other similar libraries (FakeItEasy, NSubstitute, etc.).

---

There *are* technologies available that use unsafe and arcane backdoors to change the IL of compiled code to enable you to modify (by replacing) the behaviour of any IL code, but I recommend against using them. They tend to come and go, so you could easily be stuck with an unsupported commercial piece of technology.

With such a technology, your tests are also going to be tightly coupled to implementation details, which means that every time you change even the smallest thing in your System Under Test, the tests will break. And then, what's the point of having a test suite?

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that you don't have to mock anything.
Rather than you have to populate the underlying stream and you are ready to go.

```
// Arrange
// Populate underlying stream
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
using var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.WriteLine("ID,Name");
writer.WriteLine("123,ABC");
writer.Flush();

// Setup stream reader
stream.Position = 0;
using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

// Setup csv reader
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

// Act
var actual = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().ToList();

// Assert
var expected = new List<MyClass> { new MyClass("123", "ABC") };
Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
```

Dotnet Fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2vgTJD